# How to handle event receiver with multiple ALVs in tabstrip?

Tags: abap, alv, tabstrip

I am trying to have two ALV in a tabstrip that editable by a buttom at toolbar.
There is a [nice example](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=491919846) at following page but it is a single ALV.

If we have two ALV how how to do `lcl_event_receiver` part? Do we need two of them?

Note: I am able to make teo ALV in tabstrip by looking [at this code](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=491920080)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will either need a separate event handler for every control (or at least separate handler methods) or you add an implicit parameter named `SENDER` to the event handler methods. This parameter contains the reference of the control that triggered the event, so you can compare it to the two ALV grid references and decide which one triggered the event. (In my opinion, this leads to ugly code, but in the end, that's your decision.)

Comment: So do I need to put classes to each subscreen(that holds ALV in tabstrips)  PBO? Reaaly newbie here.

Comment: Sorry to say, but if you're that new, get the proper education. A mission-critical ERP system is nothing to poke around with unless you know what you'Re doing.